# How to use data from an observable in other methods?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, reactive-programming

I am working on an Angular4 app.

Here is a service I am using to get the data-

```
export class BookingService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMemberBookings(memberID: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://myapi.com/bookings/member/'+memberID).map(response => response['bookings']); 
  }
}
```

And then in my component-

```
export class PrintButtonComponent implements OnInit {

    bookings: any;

    constructor(private service: BookingService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    downloadPDF() {      
          this.getBookings(memberID);

          //pdf creation logic
    }

    getBookings(memberID: number) {
          this.service.getMemberBookings(memberID).subscribe(data => this.bookings = data);    
    }

}
```

The problem is I want to use the data from the service in the downloadPDF method as there is other data in it that will be needed to create the PDF.
But when I return the data from the subscribe or set it to a property, it is giving undefined. I understand that this is due to asynchronous nature, but I dont want to put my pdf creation logic inside the subscribe method.
So how do I solve this problem? I am quite new to Angular and observables.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code above doesn't involve multiple values per observable and doesn't require to stick to them, this can be done with `async..await` with no extra nesting:

```
async downloadPDF() {      
      await this.getBookings(memberID);

      //pdf creation logic
}

async getBookings(memberID: number) {
      this.bookings = await this.service.getMemberBookings(memberID).toPromise();
}
```

As any other RxJS operator, `toPromise` has to be imported.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But what do you mean by 'multiple values per observable'? And is there no way to do this with the observable-subscriber method?

Comment: A promise can have one value it resolves with. An observable can have multiple emitted values. HttpClient has only one value it completes with so it can be safely replaced with a promise. You can do this with observable but you need to move 'pdf creation logic' inside `subscribe`.